# Why my circuit simulation is overly slow? Is there a way to solve this problem?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ltspice

I'm doing a project in a working for my a subject in my university. It is a remote controller, and I know much probably there's a better way to do it, but I only can use this component:
voltage switch, capacitor, inductor, current source controlled by  voltage, transistor, resistor,in other words, basic components.

I Don't know how to solve it and what's the problem source, could someone help me???
[image]
[image]
the project is in the link bellow:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13TGclP42EtCFSKa6jZXm2S6t2ftZs7oC?usp=sharing

Comment: I didn't open the project yet but normally the simulation is slow when the simulation interval is too long (1 to 10 seconds). Or the increment is too small (1u second). Can you confirm this is not the case?

Comment: the simulate time is 1.1s and the simulation speed is something about 1us to 4us.

Comment: I reduced the time simulate to 100ms but the problem remains

Comment: I don't see a power connection to the triangle parts (opamp?) Make sure all the parts have power and ground connections, otherwise it will simulate some leakage path which will be the wrong result and take a long time.

Comment: @LucasVital I can't tell whether simulating µs steps for 1.1 s is appropriate, could you explain why you think your system needs 1.1 s to settle?

Comment: In my system there's 4 relays, when I give a positive pulse, it will generate a wave voltage  dampened through the RLC serie, a peak detector will get the peak voltage and  transforms the AC signal in DC signal, finally the relay is  activated. When I give a negative pulse the relay is desactivated. The relay is represented by inductor of 100mH, and is activated when there's a current of 200mA  through the inductor and then I put this long time to test if the relay keep activated and test if others relays states  according to the input pulses.

Comment: Much problem you asked to yourself, why did he transform a DC signal in AC and DC again? it's because the AC signal is an electromagnetic wave generate by the control when the button is pressed, each pulse voltage represent a press in the button.

Comment: I downloaded your files (3) and I can't open the main schematic because `LM741_NS` is missing (symbol and subcircuit). Looking at the sources, why did you make them `PWL` when they look like they could easily have been `PULSE`? Also, you are using a generic `NMOS`, but you should either supply your own or use one from the database, since the default values are, most probably, not what you'd want. Or use a VCSW, since you're using an opamp made of a VCCS (in which case even the dreaded 741 could be replaced).